# Moving dependencies (PK, FK and indexes) from one table to another within the same database in Oracle

Tags: oracle, dependencies, partition

Please tell me how can I move dependencies (such as PK, FK and indexes) from one table to another within the same database in Oracle? The second table is a copy of the first, only created later for partition reasons. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: What have you tried, where have you looked? More detail about the efforts you have taken will encourage more people to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using the dictionary views in oracle, specifically the USER_CONSTRAINTS view. Then either construct a SQL statement dynamically or use DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl procedure to get the ddl for the constraint. You could do a REPLACE on the SQL to replace the original table name and constraint name with a new constraint name and the name of the new table.